# Not able to set font to setAdapter

Tags: android, string, fonts

Is it possible to set myFont to String[], i am doing something like that
i want to set Font to R.id.txt but all values are pass to HashMap through String[]

```js
optionsMenuList.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
    array, R.layout.custom_list_row,
    new String[] { "Name", "Image" }, new int[] { R.id.txt,
      R.id.music }));
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt)).setTypeface(Title);
```

Comment: What is Title here?

  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt)).setTypeface(Title);

Title is instance of Typeface?

Comment: Typeface Title = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
    "fonts/SegoeRg.ttf");

Thanx for your Reply....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ur R.id.txt belongs to custom_list_row xml then

```
optionsMenuList.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, array, R.layout.custom_list_row, new String[] {"Name", "Image"}, new int[] {R.id.txt, R.id.music}));
```

In ur adapter class, getView method

```
Context ctx;
SimpleAdapter(Context ctx, Object[] array, int layout, String[] stringarray, int[] intarray) {
this.ctx = ctx;
}
View v = ctx.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, null);
((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt)).setTypeface(Title);
```

Comment: hey @Harsha i got error in "context" so after i removing it i never set any kind of font to txt
so code not work.
Please help me

Comment: context is instance of your activity class, give some instance

Comment: @Yogesh Use "getApplicationContext()" instead of "context"

Comment: @YogeshMane, Don't try using application context, try to use the context of activity. and provide the error logs

Answer (score 0):

Create an object for TextView

```
        TextView tv;
        Typeface typeface = Utils.getTypeFace(activity, <get that font here)>); // get fontstyle from assets if you added 
     tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);

     public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String type) {

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fonts/SegoeRg.ttf);
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Spark what is activity here..?
Which activity i have to pass..?

Comment: getApplicationContext @YogeshMane if you use adapter. if you use Name extends Activity.. you can use Name.this

Comment: I got again NullPointerException....
I don't kw whats the problem..
The problem is tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
i pass these text to String[] thats why i thing i got NullPointerException

Comment: just try like this and check it @YogeshMane